# How to hide values from chart in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) and couldn't figure out how to hide the values on the points in my LineChart.

Screen shot:

[image]

Have you got any suggestion on how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can hide them by calling `dataSet.setDrawValues(false)` on your `LineDataSet` object.

Answer (score 2):

hide value for more than one data set

```
    Linedata data= new LineData(dataSets);
    data.setDrawValues(false);
```

hide single data set

```
    datasetname.setDrawValues(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it for all datasets `chart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(0)`